# How to go to the beginning of a selection?

Tags: mark

I selected a large region by going to the beginning line and hit `C-SPC` (currently mapped to `cua-set-mark`), and then moving to the end of the buffer with `M-S->`.

Now for some reason, I want to get back to the beginning of the selected/highlighted region where I first set the mark.

*Is there a shortcut key for going back to that position?*

(This is with Emacs 27, Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `exchange-point-and-mark`, bound to `C-x C-x`.